# iOS 5 SDK - Pushing plist data into DetailViewController (segue issue)

Tags: ios5, plist, segue

I am trying to push some plist data, which already populates my "LocationsViewController" (UITableViewController) to my "LocationsDetailViewController" (UIViewController with UILabel), when the user selects the a cell in "LocationsViewController".

In "LocationsViewController" the strings are filtered into the table perfectly, no errors. But I cannot seem to get the label to change in the "LocationsDetailViewController", and I think I'm going wrong somewhere in the prepareForSegue method.

Can anybody spot the error in my code?

Would seriously appreciate any help or advice. Thanks!!

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailViewControllerSeque"])
    {   LocationsDetailViewController *locationsDetailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"locationslist3.plist"];
        NSArray *tempArray = [finalPath valueForKey:@"countries"];
        NSString *descriptionString = [tempArray valueForKey:@"countries"];
        locationsDetailViewController.detailDescriptionLabel.text = descriptionString;
    }
}

@end
```